# PHP 5.6 and Apache on Windows, Chunks break up and output is sent to an other request

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, chunks

A very strange behaviour, haven't found anything on the net. Apache Version 2.4 running on Windows (EasyPHP), with php 5.6 current stable

Browser requests a site (`index.php?page=kdkarte_logfiles`), with post data.
Answer comes from web server, but ends after some chunks (chunked output from Apache).

Firefox requests another file (`jquery.min.js`), and the missing chunks are in the response of that second request.

So in Firefox (tested on ie as well) It looks like this (not the whole page ;-)):

```
index.php?page=kdkarte_logfiles 

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AE-Liste v3.0</title>
<script src="javascript/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head><body>.... SOME TEXT .... Query:
<select name='query'>
<option value='all' selected>Alle</option> <- EOF ->
```

next request:

jquery.min.js:

```
204c
<option value='1'>plus_service2</option><option value='4'>bremsscheibe</option><option value='5'>test</option><option value='6'>abbuchung</option><option value='7'>TESTAP47392000</option><option value='8'>test2</option><option value='9'>Hauptuntersuchung</option></select>
<input type='submit'></form></th></tr>

<tr><th>ID</th><th>GPNR</th><th>Name</th>..... MORE TEXT ....

0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 20 Mar 2017 13:35:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.6.30
Last-Modified: Wed, 18 Nov 2015 21:26:34 GMT
ETag: "1497f-524d74bedd680"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 84351
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/javascript

... jquery code ...
```

In the second response you can see hex between the chunks (204c, 203b, etc. etc.)

Looking at Wireshark, the Chunks are getting reassembled correctly. 
Tried to turn off PHP Output Buffering, any gzip compression, etc. helped nothing :-/

Next information: code on the break looks like this:

```
    </select>
Query:
<select name='query'>
<option value='all' selected>Alle</option>
<?php
$querys = query("local", true, "SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM kdkarte_query");
foreach ($querys as $query) {
    echo "<option value='".$query['id']."'>".$query['name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

so the break occurs if php is called (not the first time, though, but first time with some SQL interaction)

it only occurs if a later bigger SQL query is executed, so maybe this is a problem with php->mysql :/, if the result is only a few (let's say under 15) rows it's getting done correctly. On other Pages with Query results bigger than 1500 -> no Problem :(

chunks are mostly 8-9k bytes in size

btw. looked @ apache error log, nothing. 
done a trace with xdebug, seems ok :/

(should i ask the guys from cloudflare?! ;-))

Thanks for any help or ideas on this, folks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it... UTF-8 with BOM did this :((

Encoded to UTF-8 w/o BOM, everything works